# Mysql closing immediately after new installation

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I am using mysql as an backend for my webapp ,the software ran without any glitch but today it
gave unexpectedly **ERROR:2003** i tried many solution on the internet but none worked. so reinstalled the mysql software and now its command line closes immediately without even asking for password i am logged in as admin   . This problem is troubling me for the past 5hrs does anybody has a solution

Answer (score 1):

The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061) indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the one configured on the server.

Start by checking whether there is a process named mysqld running on your server host. (Use ps xa | grep mysqld on Unix or the Task Manager on Windows.) If there is no such process, you should start the server.

If a [mysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqld.html) process is running, you can check it by trying the following commands. The port number or Unix socket file name might be different in your setup. host_ip represents the IP address of the machine where the server is running.

```
shell> mysqladmin version
shell> mysqladmin variables
shell> mysqladmin -h `hostname` version variables
shell> mysqladmin -h `hostname` --port=3306 version
shell> mysqladmin -h host_ip version
shell> mysqladmin --protocol=SOCKET --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock version
```

**EDITED**

[Please go through the link for windows once](http://www.sitenol.com/error-2003-hy000-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost-10061)

**EDITED 2**

```
1. Run your cmd as administrator.

2.What you will see is like this
c:\windows\system32>

3.Go to your bin location by using cd..
like C:\mysql\bin(my location of bin in my computer is what you are seeing so chose yours correctly)

4.C:\mysql\bin>mysql --install
  Service successfully installed.

5.C:\mysql\bin>NET START MySql
 The MySql service is starting
 The MySql service was started successfully
```

Then last step is

```
6.C:\mysql\bin>mysql -u root - p admin
```

It will ask for password don't enter anything first time because it will use blank, n just press enter you are done.

N later you can set password too...:)

Comment: my anti virus blocked the process i unblocked it but still that error was there so reinstalled now the command line closes immediately

Comment: windows or ubuntu?

Comment: windows and while installing the istaller didnt ask to setup username,passwrd and port no

Comment: added one link for windows please go through that you can able to work it out

Comment: the mysql process is not present in my services

Comment: which version mysql u used before and now which version you have installed...

Comment: 5.6 before and after

Comment: once the mysql is installed have you started the service by using the below command.

**net start mysql**
Also add the port by using the link **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html**

Comment: it says invalid service name

Comment: As a final please check **EDITED2** by un installing and reinstall the same,

Answer (score 0):

Also check to make sure mysql is allowing connections from your computer/ip.

Comment: Also check if port is open and no firewall is rejecting connections on that port